# Generate static websites dynamically using Hugo

Tags: hugo, static-site

I'm building a static website hosting and would like to generate default web pages for my users and would like to use Hugo for this. Question is, what would be the best way to dynamically generate web pages for multiple users? This is my thought so far:

1. User fills up form for their website content e.g., photos, title, product descriptions, etc.
2. Pass to backend (I'm using Perl's Mojolicious) and create markdown files based on the provided information and save them in a designated folder created for this user
3. Run Hugo to build using those md files and move the public folder to user's root directory

This doesn't look right to me as there will be contention of multiple users to run Hugo and I'm thinking that it is much easier if I can just create the html files directly from backend instead of creating md files and then run Hugo to create the html files. Is there any better and smarter way?

Comment: Hugo is a static site generator. You're creating dynamic sites. Am curious why you need Hugo at all?

Comment: no. I am using Hugo to generate static sites. But I want to create multiple static sites dynamically from a dynamic site. Say I have 5 users registered on my site and on the back end it generates 5 static sites for each user. How do I do this with Hugo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, it seems you want to make a WordPress portal alike or something similar, going from Markdown plus theme down to HTMl/CSS/JavaScript content. The end-users edit the content in Markdown, choose the theme and the rest will be taken care of.

IMHO, there might be two ways:

(1) Using Hugo at the back-end and taking care of the destination folders and generated artifacts as well as mapping generated links to the front-end corresponding to your particular end-user's hosting. You can create a Hugo wrapper in which the input will be fed to Hugo and the generated pages will be in the `public` folder. In this way, you have to rely on an external tool (read Hugo) and wish for a long-term support version like many other systems (e.g. Ubuntu, Java, Windows).

(2) Creating a similar generator like Hugo or another (c.f. [StaticGen](https://www.staticgen.com/) for more generators on different languages). You may need the core of a Markdown based static site generator, for instance, a Markdown parser, link translators and generators, etc. With extra effort, you might have more control of every smaller component/library that you use, can configure the generated artifacts, their destinations, etc.

A side note: Markdown is a not-so-bad choice for content. Even WordPress have offered support for Markdown. Nonetheless, Markdown itself is not standardized but rather *de facto*. There are [so many flavours](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark-spec/wiki/Markdown-Flavors). You might want to look up to or stick with a good one, for example, [CommonMark](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark-spec).

Comment: thank you so much. that's exactly what I thought. For now I'll just use Hugo before moving on to creating my own generator.